# Note 10.1 stuck in restart loop

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, reboot, boot-loop, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1

I bought the Note 10.1 two months ago. But now my Note is stuck in a restarting loop for a second time. First, it happened last month. I already got that fixed by the service center. I asked the service center man whether I can fixed it by myself or not. He told me that you couldn't. Now, my Note 10.1 is constantly restarting again. I don't know what exactly the root cause of this issue is. I remembered that last activity was I only registered new account for Line and ChatOn app. The problem condition is when entering the boot screen, the note 10.1 just restarts again. So it never reaches the home screen. Any body know what is the root cause for this? How can I fix it by myself?

Comment: I've just added the 'boot-loop' tag to your question (as that is what you describe). Please check [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/boot-loop/info) for first aid, with some luck this will already solve your issue. If so, feel free to answer your own question yourself. Otherwise please [edit](http://android.stackexchange.com/posts/48372/edit) it and write what you've tried, what the outcome was, and where you're stuck then.

Comment: @Izzy, thank you for your helpful comment. I just factory reset my Note. However this is not solving the root cause. this case is happened to me twice in this three months.

Comment: In other words: while this saved you the service tech (despite him saying you couldn't do that, LOL), you're afraid it will happen again within the next 2 months. Two raw ideas: usually a "bad app" is causing this, so try remembering what you did the "last 24h". Second, to be prepared, have *USB Debugging* enabled and practice using `adb logcat` as well as `dmesg` via ADB from your computer. This might come in handy when it happens the next time, so you can hopefully capture a log of what's going on and identify the culprit.

Comment: @Izzy, thank you for your helpful comment..hope can find the root cause.

Comment: Good luck! Don't forget to come back then and update your question. You made at least me curious :)